# Java Regular expression matching error

Tags: java, expression

```
line.matches("[A-Z] ([a-zA-z][a-zA-Z]*)|\\#")
```

I need to read elements like
`"A ddg"`, `"B gH"` or `"D #"`

But it doesn't work and I need to know if the regular expression is ok.

Comment: Your explanation is not clear. Which phrases are you trying to "catch" exactly? That can help understand what you are trying to achieve. Be more specific.

Comment: What do you mean by "*I need to read elements like...*"? Do you want to find them in your line, or do you want to check if entire line is element which can be matched by this regex?

Comment: I want to check if entire line is element which can be matched by this regex

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
line.matches("[A-Z] ([a-zA-Z]+|#)")
```

Much of your regex is redundant:

- `\\#` is the same as `#` - there's nothing special about `#`
- `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*` is identical to `[a-zA-Z]+`

The thing you were missing was the correct alternation - you didn't have the closing bracket in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
line.matches("[A-Z]( [a-zA-z]+)?( #)?")
```

What will match (examples):

```
A
A #
A a
A aAaA
A a #
A aAaAa #
```

If you don't want "A #":

```
line.matches("[A-Z]( [a-zA-z]+| #)")
```

Comment: The left side(before space) is uppercase(just one character) and the right side is uppercase or/and lowercase or just #(it can be "A aa" or "B #" but no "A aa#")

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Not really sure what you wanted. Edit the question with examples if you think my solution is wrong.

Comment: FYI the leading/trailing ^ and $ are redundant. See javadoc of matches() for why

Comment: ah okay, just wanted to be sure. removed.

Answer (score 1):

You have this problems:

- you closed your parenthesis too early, which placed `#` outside of it,
- you used `A-z` range instead of `A-Z`.

Also you can improve your regex a little:

- you don't need to escape `#`
- instead of `xx*` you can use `x+` since:

  - `+` represents *once or more*
  - `*` represents *zero or more*

So try with

```
line.matches("[A-Z] ([a-zA-Z]+|#)")
```